# passing dropdown listitem value to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am having two pages..In first page am having dropdown like:

```html
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem >All</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" >Active</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem >InActive</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

from second page to first page  i have to pass InActive listitem as input using querystring

```
lnkmyCandidates.NavigateUrl = "~/Employer.aspx?value="InActive";
```

i dont know how to pass inactive as input to first page.

Comment: Do you mean: If there's a value in the querystring, you need to add a list item to the drop-down with *that* value?

Comment: question is not clear, what do u want?
Do u want that, when coming on page with ddlSatus, u need to
have a query string where a fixed value InActive should be passed as
query string? Or some thing else ???

Also u need to show what effort u put in so far to try achieving it

Comment: i need inactive as fixed value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly my suggestion would be to pass the value of the listbox rather than the text, values are often simpler and don't have things like punctuation/spaces.

Your link to the second page is correct, although make sure that you post back so the link is regenerated after the user has selected a new option in the checkbox. I assume you'd want to use the value of the dropdown

```
lnkmyCandidates.NavigateUrl = string.Concat("~/Employer.aspx?value=", ddlStatus.SlectedValue);
```

The code to receive the value from the querystring would be

```
string suppliedValue = this.Request.QueryString["value"];
```

Comment: i am getting ddlstatus doesnot exist in current context

Comment: ddlstatus is your dropdown on your first page

Answer (score 1):

Store the selected index on a session and get it from another page

How set value into session variable

```
Session["variable"] = dropdown selected value
```

And How to retrieve that on page load function

```
if (Session["variable"] != null)
{
 localVariable = (int)Session["variable"];
}
```

Comment: While this would certainly solve the problem personally I don't like this approach. It involves adding unnecessary data to session where a query string parameter would suit.